# Force Plotly hover tag

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I am using plotly and Shiny and have two plots on a single page. The points on the two plots have the same labels. Now, I would like to force a hover tag to display on plot 1 when a point with the same label is hovered on in plot 2.

I have tried to do this using the plotly postMessage API (adapted from https://github.com/plotly/postMessage-API#hover) but have not been successful. My attempt as a MWE is below. Thanks for your help.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(V8)
library(plotly)

# this is the hover javascript
hoverJSPlot2 <- "
  shinyjs.hoverPlot2 = function(params) {

    var defaultParams = {
      x : null,
      y : null
    };

    params = shinyjs.getParams(params, defaultParams);

    var plot = document.getElementById('plot1').contentWindow;

    plot.postMessage({
      'task': 'hover',
      'selection': {xval: params.x, yval: params.y},
    }, 'https://plot.ly');

  }
"

ui <- fluidPage(

  # make a bos and add a row to it.
  box(
    width = 12,

    # Row for the graphs
    fluidRow(

      # Add the first graph
      column(
        6,
        useShinyjs(),
        extendShinyjs(text = hoverJSPlot2),
        plotlyOutput("plot1")
      ),

      column(
        6,
        plotlyOutput("plot2")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  plotData1 <- reactive({
    # generate random data
    data.frame(x = rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 5),
               y = rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 5),
               label = paste0("Label - ", c(1:100)))
  })

  plotData2 <- reactive({
    # generate random data
    data.frame(x = rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 5),
               y = rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 5),
               label = paste0("Label - ", c(1:100)))
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({

    req(plotData1())

    plotData1 <- plotData1()

    plot_ly(
      data = plotData1,
      type = "scattergl",
      x = ~ x,
      y = ~ y,
      key = plotData1$label,
      hoverinfo = "text",
      text = plotData1$label,
      source = "plot1",
      mode = "markers",
      marker = list(size  =4, opacity = 0.8)
    )
  })

  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({

    req(plotData2())

    plotData2 <- plotData2()

    plot_ly(
      data = plotData2,
      type = "scattergl",
      x = ~ x,
      y = ~ y,
      key = plotData2$label,
      hoverinfo = "text",
      text = plotData2$label,
      source = "plot2",
      mode = "markers",
      marker = list(size  =4, opacity = 0.8)
    )
  })

  # begin the hover story
  hoveredPointPlot2 <- reactive({
    event_data("plotly_hover", source = "plot2")
  })

  observeEvent(hoveredPointPlot2(), {
    req(hoveredPointPlot2())

    # below doesn't work....

    hoveredPoint <- hoveredPointPlot2()
    hoveredLabel <- hoveredPoint$key

    # get the adult data
    plotData1 <- plotData1()

    plotData1 <- plotData1[plotData1$label == hoveredLabel,]

    if (nrow(plotData1) != 0) {
      js$hoverPlot2(plotData1$x, plotData1$y)
    }

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am attempting something similar but based on my own quest for answers and looking at the links you provided, I do not think it is possible using the postMessage API. postMessage documentation states:

> If you want to play with the API, the first step is to create a Plotly graph or use someone else's, then embed it in Codepen or a webpage as an iframe.

meaning that approach this is **only compatible with iframe elements.**

If you run your Shiny App in a browser and inspect the page, you'll find that your JS code `document.getElementById('plot1').contentWindow;` will not work since no iframe element named `plot1` exists. This is as far as I have gotten with this problem, and it doesn't seem like it's possible to convert an element created with `renderPlotly()` to an iframe.